# mongoexport returning scientific (exponential) notation

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

So I was exporting some collections using `mongoexport` and found cases where large integers such as `9999999999999` were exported as `9.9999999999999e+13`

So two questions: Why is this the case, and how can I prevent this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB treats all number literals as [floating point](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/) by default, and above a certain threshold (32 bits?) it switches to scientific notation when exporting to JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure how to fix this because I am not aware of a way for mongoexport to configure number formats. If you store the numbers as NumberLong, they will be exported with the strict mode representation, which is not what you want. There is no loss of precision in this case, though.

Answer (score 0):

For dumping data you can use `--eval` option of `mongo` command line client and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command. That does not give data in scientific notation.

for exmaple

```
mongo --quiet localhost:5010/user  --username alok --password alok --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'db.users.find({}, {_id: 1, username:1, name: 1}).limit(10).toArray().map(JSON.stringify).join("\n")' | while read item; do echo $(echo $item | jq ._id),$(echo $item | jq .username),$(echo $item | jq .name); done > data.csv
```