# Mongodb mongoexport number format

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I tried to export some data from MongoDb by using mongoexport.
mongoexport formats numbers greater then 1000000 as mantissa and exponent.

Ex:.  1.72361197e+06

Is there a option for mongoexport to customize the format of numbers?

Ex: 1723611.97

Any help is appreciated!

i have seen 
[mongoexport returning scientific (exponential) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961380/mongoexport-returning-scientific-exponential-notation) 
but there is no solution and It seems that there is no way to customize number format of mongoexport

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoexport returning scientific (exponential) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961380/mongoexport-returning-scientific-exponential-notation)

Comment: See also: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1418.

Comment: @JithinScaria :  mongodb 3.2.6